# Load multiple files to multiple tables in ssis

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I have two text files in some location containing column name and data.

The text files are named accordingly two blank tables created in database.

To load the data from those text files to respective tables in database I have used script task,but,the ssis package gave runtime error on execution.

Any workaround or resolution of this situation would be highly appreciated.

I am providing necessary screenshots and code below:-

**Variable:**
[image]

**Script Task Code**:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADO_TestDB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
        // MessageBox.Show(myADONETConnection.ConnectionString, "ADO_TestDB");


        //Reading file names one by one
        string SourceDirectory = Dts.Variables["User::VarFolderPath"].Value.ToString();
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            // do something with fileName
            // MessageBox.Show(fileName);
            string columname = "";


            //Reading first line of each file and assign to variable
            System.IO.StreamReader file2 =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

            string filenameonly = (((fileName.Replace(SourceDirectory, "")).Replace(".txt", "")).Replace("\\", ""));

            file2.Close();

            //Writing Data of File Into Table
            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    columname = line.ToString();

                }

                else
                {

                    string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace(",", "','") + "')";
                    //MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
                    SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                    myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                counter++;
            }
            SourceFile.Close();
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

**Error**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create two variables for the the two different path of the files and assign the path to them.
Then you can use the Foreach loop container and go ahead from their.